# Who was the first to conceive the "Two Nation Theory"?

Tags: india, pakistan

[This link](https://storyofpakistan.com/two-nation-theory-the-myth-the-reality) gives the definition of Two-nation theory:

> The two-nation theory is the basis of the creation of Pakistan. It
>   states that Muslims and Hindus are two separate nations from every
>   definition; therefore Muslims should have a separate homeland in the
>   Muslim majority areas of India, where they can spend their lives
>   according to the glorious teachings of Islam.

[This link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-nation_theory_(Pakistan)) says that 
Muhammad Ali Jinnah was the first individual to come up with "Two Nation Theory".

But, some are saying that [Veer Savarkar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinayak_Damodar_Savarkar) proposed it.

- [Veer Savarkar proposed two-nation theory, Jinnah implemented it: Bhupesh Baghel](https://www.indiatoday.in/india/story/veer-savarkar-pakistan-jinnah-bhupesh-baghel-1536292-2019-05-28)
- [Savarkar Laid Foundation of Two-Nation Theory, Congress Tells Amit Shah After Partition Swipe](https://www.news18.com/news/politics/savarkar-laid-foundation-of-two-nation-theory-congress-tells-amit-shah-after-partition-swipe-2418023.html)

Who was the first to conceive the "Two Nation Theory"?

Answer (score 3):

I found my answer.

Two nation theory was actually first proposed by [Sir Syed Ahmad Khan](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Sayyid-Ahmad-Khan).

He proposed this theory out of frustration from a series of incidents that took place during the [Urdu-Hindi controversy in 1867](https://historypak.com/urdu-hindi-controversy/) when Indian Hindus put pressure on British administrators to remove Urdu as the official language of India.

He gave the [following speech in 1888](https://yaleglobal.yale.edu/longest-august-unflinching-rivalry-between-india-and-pakistan):

> *Now, suppose that the English community and the army were to leave India, taking with them all their cannons and their splendid weapons
>   and all else, who then would be the rulers of India?*
>   ... ... ...
>   *Is it possible that under these circumstances two nations—the Mohammedans and the Hindus—could sit on the same throne and remain
>   equal in power? Most certainly not. It is necessary that one of them
>   should conquer the other. To hope that both could remain equal is to
>   desire the impossible and the inconceivable. But until one nation has
>   conquered the other and made it obedient, peace cannot reign in the
>   land.*